pydantic: make filed A as optional if filed B match some conditions
Suppose I have a student model, and what I want is that: if the age < 6, make the school optional.
What can I do? thanks in advance!
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Student(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    school: str

student = Student(**{ "name": "Tom", "age": 10, "school": "Blabla"}) # validated
baby_student = Student(**{ "name": "Tom", "age": 5}) # expected to be validated

what I have tried:
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator

class Student(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    school: str
    
    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def ignore_school_if_baby(cls, values):
        age = values.get("age")
        if age < 6:
            # don't know how to do here
            values["school"] = None
        return values

baby_student = Student(**{ "name": "Tom", "age": 5})

ValidationError: 1 validation error for Student
school
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)

also tried the below, but it still got the same error
from typing import Optional

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def ignore_school_if_baby(cls, values):
        age = values.get("age")
        if age < 6:
            annotations = cls.__annotations__
            annotations["school"] = Optional[annotations["school"]]
            cls.__annotations__ = annotations
        return values


You can wrap school in Optional type.
Also a suggestion for you, values["school"] = None will replace the data if school is still supplied., values["school"] = values.get("school") can avoid this problem.
class Student(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    school: Optional[str]

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def ignore_school_if_baby(cls, values):
        age = values.get("age")
        if age < 6:
            values["school"] = values.get("school")
        return values


thanks for your suggestion of updating school rather than override it!

and it looks make school optional can't meet my requirements: if age > 6, the school field is required

@soapcmd I tried in these operations, i think it works: baby_student = Student(**{"name": "Tom", "age": 5}) # Pass
baby_student = Student(**{"name": "Tom", "age": 5, "school": "Test"}) # Pass
baby_student = Student(**{"name": "Tom", "age": 6, "school": "Test"}) # Pass
baby_student = Student(**{"name": "Tom", "age": 6}) # Fail

Hi @HaX.Alvin, baby_student = Student(**{"name": "Tom", "age": 6}) this one is not failed with pydantic 1.10 but it will fail with pydantic 2.x I think.

required-optional-and-nullable-fields the doc says that Required, can be None f3: Optional[str]  and values["school"] = values.get("school") set the None value, I think that's why it works!

@soapcmd Oh, my mistake. I did use pydantic v2.

for pydantic v1, using school: Optional[str] = Field(...) or school: Optional[str] = ... to achieve the same results. https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/models/#required-fields
but I found that Field(..., alias="blabla") will fail this approach

from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class Student(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    school: str

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def ignore_school_if_baby(cls, values):
        age = values.get("age")
        if age < 6:
            cls.__fields__['school'].required = False
        else:
            cls.__fields__['school'].required = True
            
        return values

baby_student = Student(**{ "name": "Tom", "age": 5}) # pass
baby_student = Student(**{ "name": "Tom", "age": 6}) # failed

my stupid, I think cls.__fields__['school'].required = False works
